# What is the force on a point charge $Q$ located next to a infinite conducting plane?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

For my question as in the title, I thought that the force should be zero, because the point charge (say, positive) would induce the one side of the plane close to the point charge to the opposite charge (negative), and the other side to the same charge (positive).
Since I learned that a uniformly charged infinite plane forms an electric field of magnitude 
$${ϭ\over\epsilon_0} $$
I thought that the electric field in the area of the particle should be zero.

But the problem is that the infinite conducting plane shouldn't be uniformly charged, since a point charge induced the charges on the plane. So the formula I learned shouldn't work here. Then how can I show that the force acting on a point charge $Q$ is zero or not?

Comment: Look up "image charges".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not zero.

Your textbook probably covers this, but the $\vec E$ field is the gradient of a voltage field and a good conductor maintains a constant voltage; this constancy of voltage will "leak" somewhat to the space outside causing the voltage near the surface to be constant, too. This means that the $\vec E$ field in the space around the conductor must point normal to it, near its surface.

There is an elegant way to solve this problem by simply trying to invent an imaginary charge distribution (the "method of image charges") inside of the conductor which, if the conductor were not there, would also guarantee that plane-of-constant-voltage and therefore $\vec E$-normal-to-the-surface boundary condition. You may not 100% believe me on this, but if you do the math then the force on the one charge distribution due to the conductor *must be exactly* equal to the force due to this "image charge distribution." This is a deep consequence of the principle of superposition and a statement of the uniqueness of the voltage field given its boundary conditions etc.

In this elegant way, one sees that for an infinite conductor spread out on the $xy$-plane, one can immediately cancel out the transverse components $E_{x,y}$ of the electric field of a point charge $Q$ at $(0, 0, +z)$ by inventing an imaginary point charge $-Q$ at $(0, 0, -z)$, which would have the same $E_z$ component but negative $E_{x, y}$ components on that plane. Therefore the force on the charge $Q$ due to the conductor is going to be just $\vec E = -\hat z~k_e~Q^2/(2z)^2$ due to the Coulomb's law force between it and the imaginary charge.